# It is possible to use for loop inside arrow function shorthand?

Tags: javascript

I have following arrow function with for-loop

```js
f = x=> { for(let i=0; i<10; i++) console.log(i+x); return 5+x }

f(2);
```

I want to use arrow function shorthand and remove `return` statement - however only way that I can do it is remove `for` (and use some alternative loop)

```js
f = x=> ( [...Array(10)].forEach((y,i)=> console.log(i+x)), 5+x )

f(2);
```

However I would like to use 'original' `for` but When I do it then I get an error:

```js
f = x=> ( for(let i=0; i<10; i++) console.log(i+x), 5+x )

f(2);
```

> Unexpected token 'for'

Is it possible to use `for` statement inside the arrow function shorthand (which returns a value without explicit `return` statement)?

Comment: TL;DR: Not really, because of JS syntax rules.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is possible to use `for` statement inside the arrow function shorthand - just wrap it by non-shorthand function: `(()=>{ ...loop... })()` (this is indirect solution but still in question frame)

```js
f = x=> ( (()=>{ for(let i=0; i<10; i++) console.log(i+x) })(), 5+x )

f(2);
```

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not possible, because a [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) is not an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions).

From [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> ### [Function body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)
>
> Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block body".
>
> In a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the implicit return value. In a block body, you must use an explicit `return` statement.